# How can I check my filesystem with the new Disks 3.4.1?

Tags: gnome, filesystem, disk-utility, 12.10

Disks 3.4.1 (aka palimpsest, gnome-disk-utility, or Disk Utility) underwent a huge UI change, and I can't find something comparable to the old "check filesystem" button in its UI. Where can I find this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Note:** Users of Ubuntu 12.04 Precise will not experience this issue because Disks 3.4.1 is only available via PPA or in the next Ubuntu release, 12.10 Quantal.

- Disks 3.3+ is a complete rewrite of the old `gnome-disk-utility` (aka Palimpsest). It no longer appears to include an option to check filesystems:

  [image]
- Use GParted to check filesystems instead. Select the partition you want to check, click on Partition...Check in the menu:

  [image]
- The operation will be added to the list. Click on the Apply button to start the check:

  [image]

Comment: By `gnome-disk-utitility`, do you mean `gnome-disk-utility`(Note lack of extra ti's)

Comment: I'm confused by the "Users of precise will not notice this". What PPA is this on? It somehow installed itself on my 12.04 system... Otherwise, good answer, and thank you for the helpful, detailed information. :)

Comment: @weberc2 the "official" version in Precise is the old 3.0.2. The new one appears to be available in [at least 8 PPAs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=gnome-disk-utility+precise), if not more, so it's easy to get it even if you didn't want to. To find out where it came from, run `apt-cache showpkg gnome-disk-utility | grep 3.4.*ppa` and look for the part after `launchpad.net_`. The first set of underscores encloses the maintainer and the second the PPA archive name. To restore, do a `sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility=3.0.2-2ubuntu7` and then hold `gnome-disk-utility`.

Comment: Sure enough, it came in on Gnome3 team or some such. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Wow. This should be a bug. Isn't a loss a functionality a regression?

Answer (score 1):

As I was unable to find this functionality, I found the following workaround provided the same end result for my purposes:

Run `fsck /dev/sda2` in a terminal window (in which `/dev/sda2` is the path to whichever filesystem you'd like to check).